# Building several one-to-many relationships

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

It implements the model as seen below:

[image]

I implement three classes of models:

```
@Entity
public class Home implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "home")
    private Set<UserHome> userHomes;
}
@Entity
public class UserHome implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "home_id")
    private Home home;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userhome")
    private Set<Key> keys;
}
@Entity
public class Key implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userhome_id")
    private UserHome userHome;
}
```

When you try to compile it gets an error:

> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.example.homeUser.Key.userhome in com.example.homeUser.UserHome.keys

I do not know what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your code, the lowercase h in `userhome`:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "userhome")
private Set<Key> keys;
```

Should be (uppercase H):

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "userHome")
private Set<Key> keys;
```

The fields/properties you reference in a field like `mappedBy` should have the exact name and case of the field in the JavaBean.